# Angular 8 post formData to ASP.NET Core API cannot bind IEnumerable/List

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular8

As title says

TypeScript model

```
export interface RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaData {
  id: number;
  id_ordine: number;
  id_taglio_buono_spesa: number;
  quantita: number;
}
```

which is part of another bigger object:

```
export class OrdiniBuoniSpesaData {
  id: number;
  // OTHER FIELD
  // OTHER FIELD
  // OTHER FIELD
  righe_ordine: RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaTableData;
}
```

Save method

```
saveOrder(model: OrdiniBuoniSpesaData) {
    const headerPost: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headerPost.set('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_cliente', model.id_cliente.toString());
    // VARIOUS FORM FIELDS
    //THIS IS ARRAY DATA
    formData.append('righe_ordine', JSON.stringify(model.righe_ordine));
    return this.http
        .post<boolean>(
          requestURL,
          formData,
          { headers: headerPost }
        )
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

Order json (valid Json) is visible in Chrome request capture clearly along with all data:

```
[{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":1,"quantita":1},{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":1,"quantita":1},{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":1,"quantita":1},{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":3,"quantita":14}]
```

On API Side

Receiving model for JSON

```
public class RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long id_ordine { get; set; }
    public long id_taglio_buono_spesa { get; set; }
    public int quantita { get; set; }
}
```

Which is in

```
public class OrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel 
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        //OTHER VARIOUS FIELDS
        //I TRIED ALSO WITH LIST INSTEAD OF IENUMERABLE
        public IEnumerable<RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel> righe_ordine {get;set;}
    }
```

(I TRIED ALSO WITH LIST INSTEAD OF IENUMERABLE, STILL NO LUCK!)

Api controller signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostSaveOrder([FromForm] OrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel model) 
{.....code}
```

All the fields are binded correctly except for the righe_ordine array!
I can see every field correctly but the array has count = 0.

Strangely enough, if I examine the asp net request object (this.Request.Form) in the QuickWatch debug in visual studio:

```
this.Request.Form["righe_ordine"]
{[{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":1,"quantita":1},
{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":1,"quantita":1},
{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":1,"quantita":1},
{"id":0,"id_ordine":0,"id_taglio_buono_spesa":3,"quantita":14}]}    

Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues
```

is present and correctly populated..... but for some reason binding it to the OrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel fails....

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

**EDIT:**

For the moment the only solution I found is to directly catch the value just after entering the controller:

```
string righeJson = this.Request.Form["righe_ordine"].ToString();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(righeJson))
      model.righe_ordine = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel>>(righeJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your model name like this

In your js code

```
formData.append('righeOrdine', JSON.stringify(model.righe_ordine));
```

and c#

```
public class OrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel 
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        //OTHER VARIOUS FIELDS
        //I TRIED ALSO WITH LIST INSTEAD OF IENUMERABLE
        public IEnumerable<RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel> RigheOrdine {get;set;}
    }
```

Update: Just for enhancement

Maybe you need to parse it before using it in your controller

You can read my full code [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/01/22/parse-json-string-with-json-net/)

We will need to create interface and class to implement it.

```
public interface IJsonParseService<T> where T : class
{
     T ToObject(string json);
}

public class JsonParseService<T> : IJsonParseService<T> where T : class
{
    public T ToObject(string json)
    {
      return JObject.Parse(json).Root.ToObject<T>();
    }
}
```

Then register it

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IJsonParseService<>), typeof(JsonParseService<>));
```

So your code should be something like this

```
private readonly IJsonParseService<RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel> _jsonParsePostOptionDefaultVm;

jsonParsePostOptionDefaultVm.ToObject(viewModel.RigheOrdiniBuoniSpesaViewModel);
```

Comment: In other projects I parsed IEnumerables correctly, If I have to do that my current workaround is sufficient then.

Thanks!

Comment: Nigo are you sure about that? Just for reference other fields in my model are:
   public long id_cliente { get; set; }
        public long id_modalita_pagamento { get; set; }

And so on and so far they have no problem with that naming convention with underscores

Comment: I've tried you new solution but nothing changed, still no result, I have to do it manually